# retain count of a view controller not equal zero after a release message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view controller initialized like this: `HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];`

Then I've placed this method after I finished working with this view controller: `[homeVC release];` **and right after it** i've placed `NSLog@("%d",[homeVC retainCount]);` the console displays 15 as a `retainCount` number, however, I put double `[homeVC release];` lines and the same `NSLog` statement, result = app crashes ...

two questions:

1) can anybody explain that ?

2) how can I make the `retainCount` to be equal Zero ?

Comment: The `retainCount` will never go to zero. Even if it did the object would be deallocated so sending a message to it would not make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Various parts of code internal to the iOS SDK can/will retain your view controller as well, particularly if you are pushing to it, presenting it modally, associating it with a tab control, or doing pretty much any other nontrivial thing with it.  In short, you are not the only one making use of your view controller.  And your crash happens simply because adding the second release causes the view controller to eventually be released one too many times.

   Moreover, manually inspecting the retain count of an object is not generally recommended, specifically because of cases such as this where the actual value does not match the value a developer might expect.
2. By matching every `alloc/init`, `retain`, and `copy` with a call to `release`, and by not worrying about precisely when the retain count reaches exactly zero (if you really want to know when this happens, set a breakpoint in `dealloc`).  You have to write code that does not leak or over-release objects, assume that the iOS SDK will do the same, and trust that your object will be released at the correct point in time.  Alternately, switch to SDK version 5 and use automatic garbage collection instead.

Comment: I'd add that **"`retainCount` is nonsense. don't call it."**.  Otherwise, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not use retainCount**. It is meaningless. Just follow the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH), release when you're the owner, and you will be OK.

Comment: i do not use it, im just testing the view controller to see its retain count ... im using it for testing only ..

Comment: `retainCount` is just as useless for testing as it is for anything else.

Comment: bbum: so why Apple left this method in the SDK ? just because it's useless ?